# Changing CXXFLAGS in R CMD INSTALL for developing R packages

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to debug a package that I'm developing.  I use a [makefile](https://gist.github.com/1374344) for building, checking and installing the packages.  The packages is an Rcpp package and so already has a makevars and makevars.win file in it.  What I am looking for is a was to have CXXFLAGS changed just for a specific make rule.  Then `make debug` will run `R CMD INSTALL` with `CXXFLAGS= -Wall -pedantic -g -O0"` but regular `make install` will run with `CXXFLAGS=-O3` without any debugging info.  is there a good way to dynamically change this without having to modify my package, personal or system makevars files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so as there is only one `CXXFLAGS` to go around.  But you could reassign again in differnt 'make' vs `make debug' target portions.

You could just keep two versions `~/.R/Makevars.normal` amd `~/R/Makevars.debug` and use a script to flip a link between them...

For what it is worth. I just edit `~/.R/Makevars` and comment/uncomment different lines.

*Edit:* What about something like this, based on the `Makefile` you posted:

```
install: $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
    CXXFLAGS+="-O3" R CMD INSTALL $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz

debuginstall: $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
    CXXFLAGS+="-Wall -g -O0" R CMD INSTALL $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
```

*Edit 2:*  I just played with this, and it works:

```
PKG_NAME=digest
PKG_VERSION=0.5.1

install: $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
    PKG_CFLAGS="-O6" R CMD INSTALL $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz

debuginstall: $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
    PKG_CFLAGS="-Wall -g -O0" R CMD INSTALL $(PKG_NAME)_$(PKG_VERSION).tar.gz
```

It *still* reads my `~/.R/Makevars` afterwards so certain vars cannot be set here.  But you could just set `MYDEBUG=...` in your `Makefile` and then use that inside a definition in `~/.R/Makevars`.

Comment: do you think that the R core team would entertain the idea of allowing something like this?

Comment: Also is there no way through environment variables or anything like that to accomplish it?

Comment: You can make it work with env variables too; that is a basic `make` feature.

Comment: the debuginstall rule does not work.  errors with `/bin/sh: CXXFLAGS+= -Wall -pedantic -g -O0: not found`  Does it work on your system?

Comment: I was shooting from the hip, but I have done similar tricks with Makefiles. Try without the `+=`, and just `=`.  Else assign to `MYCXXFLAGS` and expand that in the `Makefile` into `CXXFLAGS` proper.  Also consider `PKG_CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: Thinko on my part. You can't assign on the same line as you would in shell, you need to do it on line above.   Or just punt and define shellwrapper `RcmdInstallDbg` and `RcmdInstall` ....

Comment: I'm not sure what the last comment was about because it worked as is in your post.  Thank you.